# Windows Identy Foundation and Flex

Tags: .net, apache-flex, wif

i am just wondering if there is some custom way to allow flex interaction against Windows identity foundation. Basically what i want, i just delegate the authentication process from a flex app to a IP-STS, there is some support on FLEX Side to achieve this?
regards

Comment: If Windows IDentity Foundation is a server based software that exposes its authentication service via some API; you can probably do it.  If it isn't you won't be access it from a browser based Flex app; but may be able to do so from an AIR app using NativeProcess APIs.

Comment: yeah well it could expose a STS through WS-Trust or SAML, there is some library on action script to work with WS-trust or SAML? regards

Comment: I don't know what most of the terms you used are.  If you can expose the services via some web based API; then you can access it using SOAP or REST (HTTP).  In Flex that would be HTTPService or WebService classes.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of Windows Identity Foundation, however after doing a quick google search and [finding this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236592%28v=PROT.10%29.aspx) it seems to be that since a normal HTTP request can get it going, it should be fairly easy to do so using Flash since all of Flash's HTTP communication is done through the browser it's playing in.